# Filtering data form select SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering

I don't know how to ask my question. Please see the screenshot.

Screenshot #1:

[image]

I have this table as shown in screenshot #1, and I want to filter it as shown in screenshot #2.

Please help do that. Thanks a lot.

Screenshot #2:

[image]

Comment: Can you **explain** in plain English what you want to do? Don't just let us **guess** what you might try to achieve!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: I mean with all most columns of one row are the same value except the STATUS column. When the value of the Status column is failed or passed. We have the last value is failed. Something like that.

Comment: I had a solution to this issue. thank all